# Building models and estimators in tf2.0 without tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Given that layers API has been deprecated, how do I build models in tf2 without using tf.keras (or what is the recommended way to build models)? Issue [#30829](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30829) has the same question, but was closed without any answers.

Update:

I'm okay with using `tf.keras.layers` instead of `tf.layers`, but once I've built all the layers and I need to return the model, is there a way to *NOT* use `keras` model, compile, fit, predict and evaluate, and just do it the tensorflow's way?

*If you were wondering why I would want to do something like that, it is that I would like to use estimators to train, rather than keras' fit function. There exists a [`keras_model_to_estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/estimator/model_to_estimator), but it seems it's not [mature](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21983#issuecomment-455388489) [enough](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21983#issuecomment-418826230) [yet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26804#issuecomment-515377059)*

Answer (score 0):

Google released migration guide from TF 1 to TF 2, [section Converting Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#converting_models).

**Recommended way to build models**

[Guide (section "Models based on tf.layers")](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#models_based_on_tflayers) recommends to convert `tf.layers` models to `tf.keras.layers`:

> The conversion was one-to-one because there is a direct mapping from v1.layers to tf.keras.layers.

**Build models without Keras**

The option is to provide own layer implementations (example from the guide):

```py
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(2,2)), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(2)), name="b")

@tf.function
def forward(x):
  return W * x + b

out_a = forward([1,0])
print(out_a)
```

But it is worth to consider `tf.keras.layers.Layer` ([example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#mixed_variables_v1layers)), which gives some degree of freedom, but integrate with rest of Keras (and it's layers).

Even with layers written with `tf.keras`, you are able to write own training loop ([example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#write_your_own_loop)).

To sum up, in practice TF 2.0 requires you to use `tf.keras`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could have been more descriptive that I had problems when returning the models after building; I have just updated the question.

Comment: Michal, could you clarify your last sentence: "To sum up, in practice TF 2.0 requires you to use tf.keras"? IIUC, in the rest of your answer you show how to build models without Keras?